# Set newline in Java swing window

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, multiline

I am trying to set a couple newlines in a java swing window, but for some reason everything is printed on one line.

This is my code:

```
private JLabel lblOutput;
guess = 79;
numberOfTries = 5;
message = guess + " is correct. " + "\n" + "Let's play again! "  + "\n" + "And it only took you " + numberOfTries + " number of tries!";
lblOutput.setText(message);
```

The output of the above is:

```
79 is correct. Let's play again! And it only took you 5 number of tries!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use a JTextArea if you want to display multiple String lines.

Answer (score 3):

A label is designed to only display a single line of text.

However, you can use simple HTML to split the text on multiple lines:

```
label.setText("<html>line1<br>line2</html>");
```

Comment: FYI, the closing `</html>` is not required.

Comment: @Abra good to know, the less chance of me making a typing mistake the better...

Answer (score 3):

If lblOutput is a JLabel, it only accepts a single line of text.

[You can try using HTML formatting to get around it.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)